# Android - ActionBarToggle method not resolved by Android Studio

Tags: android, actionbardrawertoggle

I'm trying to implement Material Navigation Bar. I followed someone's tutorial for it. But I'm facing a little problem. Android Studio resolves everything except for drawer_open and drawer_close parameters for the constructor of ActionBarDrawerToggle e.g.

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close)
```

Here it fails to resolve drawer_open and drawer_close. Google's Navigation Drawer sample works perfectly fine. I have imported all necessary packages. I can't figure out what's going wrong since I've just started learning android.
Full code of MainActivitiy is:

```
    package com.startup.demo;

import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //First We Declare Titles And Icons For Our Navigation Drawer List View
    //This Icons And Titles Are holded in an Array as you can see

    String TITLES[] = {"Home","Events","Mail","Shop","Travel"};
    //int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_home,R.drawable.ic_events,R.drawable.ic_mail,R.drawable.ic_shop,R.drawable.ic_travel};

    //Similarly we Create a String Resource for the name and email in the header view
    //And we also create a int resource for profile picture in the header view

    String NAME = "Akash Bangad";
    String EMAIL = "akash.bangad@android4devs.com";
    //int PROFILE = R.drawable.aka;

    private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;                           // Declaring RecyclerView
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;                        // Declaring Adapter For Recycler View
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;            // Declaring Layout Manager as a linear layout manager
    DrawerLayout Drawer;                                  // Declaring DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;                  // Declaring Action Bar Drawer Toggle




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Assinging the toolbar object ot the view
    and setting the the Action bar to our toolbar
     */
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView); // Assigning the RecyclerView Object to the xml View

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);                            // Letting the system know that the list objects are of fixed size

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,NAME,EMAIL);       // Creating the Adapter of MyAdapter class(which we are going to see in a bit)
        // And passing the titles,icons,header view name, header view email,
        // and header view profile picture

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);                              // Setting the adapter to RecyclerView

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);                 // Creating a layout Manager

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);                 // Setting the layout Manager


        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);        // Drawer object Assigned to the view
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                // code here will execute once the drawer is opened( As I dont want anything happened whe drawer is
                // open I am not going to put anything here)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                // Code here will execute once drawer is closed
            }



        }; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle); // Drawer Listener set to the Drawer toggle
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();               // Finally we set the drawer toggle sync State

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following string in strings.xml

drawer_open = "xxx"
drawer_close = "xxx"